# Fast calculation of the area of intersection between a sphere and a cylinder

Tags: metric-geometry

In my current research, I am looking at calculating the local porosity of a porous media in cylindrical coordinate (notably, two co-centric cylinders).

To obtain an accurate approximation, I need to calculate the area of intersection between the surface of a cylinder with a radius $R$ for which the axis is in $(0,0,0)$ and a sphere of radius $r<R$ for which the center can vary (i.e it can be anywhere between the two co-centric cylinders).

Could somebody point me in the direction of an analytical solution to calculate the area of intersection between these two surfaces or at least a fast algorithm?

Best regards,
BB

Answer (score 2):

These two references might help:

> (1) Murilo G. Coutinho.
>   *Dynamic Simulations of Multibody Systems*.
>   Springer, 2001. ([Springer link](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4757-3476-8))
>   
>   [image: Contents]
>
> (2) James Miller. "Geometric approaches to nonplanar quadric surface intersection curves." *ACM Transactions on Graphics (TOG)* 6.4 (1987): 274-307.
>   ([ACM link](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=35041))
>   
>    
>    
>    
>    
>    
>    
>    
>    
>   [image: Figure11]

Comment: Thank you, that seems like exactly what I want. :)